# Multiple web applications in a single container - How many instances of JVM?

Tags: java, weblogic

If multiple web applications are running in a container - for example Weblogic. Is it each application runs on different instance of JVM or same instance of JVM ? What about the class loaders, is it different for different web application. If it is different, what is the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Weblogic, a JVM is allocated to the [managed server](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/domain_config/understand_domains.html#1102073) instance. If this managed server is configured to use multiple web applications, all run on the same JVM. However web applications that are deployed to different servers would naturally run on those individual JVM's.

As for class loaders, generally, the class loaders (for multiple web applications) are the same. The reason I say generally is, it is [still possible to override](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP659) and use a different class loader by configuring the deployment descriptor weblogic.xml

Rationale for using different class loader would be, say, if weblogic uses the most recent version of a common library, but your application was bulit on an older version.